# Is there a way to hook a before and after suite, in a Rakefile?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, rakefile

My current Rakefile looks like this:

```
# ...

task :test do
    # build testing environment
    RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
        # ...
    end
    Rake::Task["spec"].execute
    # remove testing environment
end
```

Unfortunately this does not execute anything after `Rake::Task["spec"].execute` for some reasons that I can't possibly conceive.

So, is there a way to specify something to execute before and after the test suite runs, **within the Rakefile**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your specs failed, maybe that's why nothing after `Rake::Task["spec"].execute` gets executed.  Instead of using the Rakefile, why not use Rspec's `before(:suite)` and `after(:suite)` hooks?  You can put that code in your `spec_helper.rb` if you have one.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#before/after-blocks-defined-in-config-are-run-in-order

Comment: "You can put that code in your spec_helper.rb if you have one." -- "... ***within the Rakefile?***"

Comment: No, within the file named `spec_helper.rb` which is a different file.  Most people have a `spec/spec_helper.rb` and in their specs they write `require 'spec_helper'`.